# How to reset pedometer sensor and make its value zero in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using pedometer plugin in flutter to access mobile pedometer sensor for step counting, but now I am stuck how to reset the pedometer sensor and to make its value zero after completion of 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Scheduler` to do this task.
Use `cron` package to run your task periodically.
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cron
I hope this will be helpful